# DELETE SQL operation with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have problem with SQL DELETE in PHP language. I don't know where is the problem about delete sql operation.
Could you help me, please?

The code is:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connessione, "SELECT * FROM (SELECT date, time, temperature FROM streamcopy WHERE moteid = '".$sensor."' AND CONCAT(DATE, ' ',TIME) BETWEEN '".$i."' AND '".$f."' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC) AS tab ORDER BY date, time");

$n = 0;
$m = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    if($n == 0){
        $num = $row['temperature']; //OK
        $n = $n+1;
    }
    else{
        $temp[$m] = $row; //OK
        if(abs($num - $temp[$m]['temperature'])<0.5){ //OK
            $queryFIXED = mysqli_query($connessione, "DELETE FROM streamcopy WHERE moteid = '".$sensor."' AND temperature = '".$temp[$m]['temperature']."' AND date = '".$temp[$m]['date']."' AND time = '".$temp[$m]['time']."')"); /* elimina dati di temperatura k vicini */
            $n = $n+1;
            $m = $m+1;
        }
        else{
            $num = $temp[$m]['temperature'];
            $n = $n+1;
            $m = $m+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: you have one extra closing brace ) at the end of query ".$temp[$m]['time']."')"; remove that extra brace hope it will work.

Comment: put `or die(mysqli_error($$connessione))` beside of both mysqli_query and check the exact error. and the erroris extra bracket also in query(second) $queryFIXED = mysqli_query($connessione, "DELETE FROM streamcopy WHERE moteid = '".$sensor."' AND temperature = '".$temp[$m]['temperature']."' AND date = '".$temp[$m]['date']."' AND time = '".$temp[$m]['time']."'"); /* elimina dati

Comment: No errors :) The delete operation doesn't work then the records on DB are not deleted.

Comment: the error is extra bracket also in query(second)  `$queryFIXED = mysqli_query($connessione, "DELETE FROM streamcopy WHERE moteid = '".$sensor."' AND temperature = '".$temp[$m]['temperature']."' AND date = '".$temp[$m]['date']."' AND time = '".$temp[$m]['time']."'");`

Comment: Try to debug to get the raw query and try to execute that query manual to see if there're any error.

Comment: To cancel the extra bracket (tks for underline that error) I received the error: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: Darian, I've just tried and the query works

Comment: After removing extra bracket i think?

Comment: After removing extra bracket I have `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`

Comment: didi you put die as i mentioned in my previous comment just beside your both mysqli_query

Comment: Ya, but the response is the same